# calculating transaction amount for the following week

Tags: google-bigquery

Transaction -> Transaction_id, buyer_id, seller_id, object_id,Shipping_id, Price, Quantity, site_id,transaction_date, expected_delivery_date, check_out_status
                            leaf_category_id, defect_id

Buyer -> Buyer_id, name, country

Seller -> Seller_id, name, country, segment, standard

Listing -> object_id, seller_id, auction_start_date
               auction_end_date, listing_site_id, leaf_category_id
               quantity

For the sellers from UK who transacted on the second week of december(6 December 2015 to 12 December 2015), find the number of sellers
who have atleast twice the total transaction amount (qty*price) in the following week.

I have tried below query to get sellers who transacted in dec 2nd week but facing error when calculating sellers having twice the transaction amount from those sellers in following week.

```
With trans_dec_uk as
(
select s.seller_id,t.transaction_date, sum(t.Qty * Price) trans_amount
from transaction t join seller s
on t.seller_id =s.seller_id
where s.country ='UK'
and t.transaction_date between '12-05-2015' and '12-18-2015'
group by s.seller_id,t.transaction_date
)
select count(seller) from  trans_dec_uk
where trans_amount =  2 * to_char(sysdate+7,'DD-MM')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with uk_sellers as (
 select * from <dataset>.Seller where country = 'UK'
),
first_week_uk as (
  select seller_id, sum(Price*Quantity) as first_week_total
  from <dataset>.Transaction
  inner join uk_sellers using(seller_id)
  where transaction_date between '2015-12-05' and '2015-12-11'
  group by 1
),
second_week_uk as (
  select seller_id, sum(Price*Quantity) as second_week_total
  from <dataset>.Transaction
  inner join uk_sellers using(seller_id)
  where transaction_date between '2015-12-12' and '2015-12-18'
  group by 1
)
select count(distinct seller_id) as the_answer
from first_week_uk
inner join second_week_uk using(seller_id)
where second_week_total >= 2*first_week_total
```